# How to securely store Encryption keys in Salesforce?

Tags: encryption, salesforce, apex

We have a package that needs to use an encryption key to encrypt/decrypt data in an object. The current thought is to store this key in a protected custom setting within Salesforce. Are there other options exist for storing keys securely?

Is there a commercial grade cert issued by a Cert. Authority that can be easily moved between various Orgs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a protected custom seeing within your managed package would work best since it would only be assigned from within your managed package or a protected custom metadata types are another option that you should look into.